# jquery .on("click") not working after .off("click")

Tags: jquery

I could use some help debugging this:

```
var factBody = jQuery(".fact__body");

jQuery(".fact").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(".fact").not(this).addClass("fact-inactive");
    jQuery(this).addClass("fact-active");
    jQuery(".fact").off("click");

    var indexOfClicked = jQuery(this).index();
    var descriptionOfIndex = 
    jQuery(".fact__description").eq(indexOfClicked - 1);

 jQuery(factBody).show().addClass("active").append(descriptionOfIndex);
});

jQuery(".fact-close").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(factBody).hide().removeClass("active");
    jQuery(".fact").removeClass("fact-inactive fact-active");
    jQuery(".fact").on("click");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/left23/yyoxpk9j/

After an item is clicked, I remove the click handler using .off method. This works. So when the text panel is displayed, the items are no longer clickable. This is how I am preventing more than one panel from opening at one time.

When the text panel is closed, by clicking on the 'close' button, I try to add the click handler again, but this fails. I can't see clearly why.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: `.on("click")` is missing the function to call when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `.on('click')` doesn't have a memory of what your previous events were. You need to make it into a function you can recall, as so

```
var factBody = jQuery(".fact__body");
var handleClickEvent = function() {
  jQuery(".fact").not(this).addClass("fact-inactive");
  jQuery(this).addClass("fact-active");
  jQuery(".fact").off("click", handleClickEvent);

  var indexOfClicked = jQuery(this).index();
  var descriptionOfIndex = 
      jQuery(".fact__description").eq(indexOfClicked - 1);

  jQuery(factBody).show().addClass("active").append(descriptionOfIndex);
}

jQuery(".fact").on("click", handleClickEvent);

jQuery(".fact-close").on("click", function() {
  jQuery(factBody).hide().removeClass("active");
  jQuery(".fact").removeClass("fact-inactive fact-active");
  jQuery(".fact").on("click", handleClickEvent);
});
```

Comment: thanks @Joe Lissner, this is what I was missing. And such a fast response :)